# I am trying to get the length of an array from my rails api with react

Tags: reactjs

When I try to fetch the array it gives me the total number of characters for length. How do I only show the number of total requests?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            requests:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() 
    {
     axios.get("http://localhost:3003/requests")
        .then(res => {
        const requests = res.data;
        const total = res.data.length; 
            this.setState({ requests, total});
    });
        }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>
                  Amount of Requests: {this.state.total}
                </h1>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Counter
```

My component, when rendered shows that the amount of requests is 3149, when it should only be 5. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is that you are getting in `res.data` from backend? Can you do `console.log` or `debug` and check?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
class Counter extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            // declare the default state of total beforehand, so that
            // render has something to work with before the ajax request is finished
            total: 0,
            requests: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:3003/requests").then(({data}) => {
            // set the values correctly in setState
            this.setState({ 
                requests: data, 
                total: data.length 
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        // what i changed here was optional, for readability
        return <div><h1>Amount of Requests: { this.state.total }</h1></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Throws an error saying cannot find length of undefined